# Can't install apps using sudo apt-get install: unable to lock the administration directory

Tags: apt, sudo, lock

I can't install some applications using `apt-get`.

It shows the following error. How to solve it?

```
$ sudo apt-get install apache2
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Answer (score 2):

#### This may break things if used carelessly. Try the answers on this question first: [Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?](https://askubuntu.com/q/15433/301745)

Did you have a problem while you were installing something previously? Your computer may've crashed while apt, apt-get or aptitude was doing some updates and so it left the lock file in the disk.

Try this:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock_backup
```

Then try to install apache again:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

If everything works fine, just delete the backup file:

```
sudo rm -vf /var/lib/dpkg/lock_backup
```

Comment: Note that the contents of the file itself (/var/lib/dpkg/lock) are not important. It's its presence at that path that prevents bad things from happening. So there's no reason to make a backup.